# PHP-jQuery-html: How to populate a dropdown list while keeping existing value

Tags: php, jquery, html

First, please excuse the lack of code sample but I'm typing this from my phone.

I have a form that when the page loads, it automatically populates the fields with the user data as readonly. (This would be the default values).

Some of those fields are select options and what I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks the edit and the form is no longer readonly, I need those dropdown lists to show the user all available options while displaying the default value as the initial selected option.

I know it might be troublesome to help without code samples but my hands are kinda tied.

If it helps, the form gets auto populated through a php/mysql query only. No js/jq involved in the process except to enable and disable the form fields.

Comment: It's not only troublesome but likely sufficiently off topic to be voted down and closed. It is not clear if you are just looking for a "php cascading dropdown"  which has hundreds of answers

Comment: I know but i had to give it a shot anyway. I'll see it I can update the question with an image showing helpful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=populatedropdown', "root", "");

$query = $dbh->query("select * from position"); // Run your query

echo '<form action="populate.php" method="get">';
echo '<select name="populate">'; // Open your drop down box



// Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';// Close your drop down box


echo '<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">';

echo '</form>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. You gave me an idea on how to approach what I want to do. It's not a direct response to my question, but it will do for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad a lot. You are my first points! Thank you very much!